# Store value from user input to variable (in a function)

Tags: python, function, loops

New to python. Here is what I am looking at

```
def input(check):

Check if the input by the user is bigger 0 and assign the user input result (Boolean) to a variable
Check if the input by the user is smaller than 180  and assign the user input result (Boolean) to another variable
```

If both variables contains `true`, then return `true` or other cases return `False`

How to code it?

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you're looking at. Do you have a question?

Comment: I apologize. The question is how to do it...

Comment: Okay. Can you please add your attempt thus far? It will make people on here much much more willing to help. Generally it's nice to see some code that you have tried to work out, even if it doesn't work how you want it to.

Comment: `input()` is a builtin function for Python 3. Is this from your homework?

Answer (score 1):

The `input` function is already built-in to Python.

```
def my_function():
    user_input = int(input('Enter a number: ')) # raw_input if Python 2

    a = user_input > 0
    b = user_input < 180

    return a and b # test if both are true

my_function() # call the function
```

Comment: A one line return: `return 0 < int(input('Enter a number: ')) < 180` but that doesn't allow for try/except. Probably `return 0 < user_input < 180` then.

Comment: The OP wanted the values stored as Booleans.

Answer (score 0):

@Ravi you need to choose another name since `input` is taken for a built-in function. You could code the desired function with the NewNameFunction like this:

```
def NewNameFunction (check):    
   a= check > 0
   b= check < 180   
   return (a and b)
```